# Redirect to homepage after for is submitted

Tags: python, flask

Trying to have my web app to redirected to the home page after the form is submitted but it just gives the form's query in the address bar. For example /form?Name=input&Location=input

script.py

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/form", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def form():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("form.html")
    else:

        return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

form.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form >
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <input type="text" name="Location">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me! I don't see anything wrong with your code!

Comment: how? Did you return an html file or did you return a form because for some reason it works fine when you return form in script.py but not if your form is in an html file

Comment: can you share your index.html if you don't mind. I rendered the form as part of an html file. Maybe you are not making all the correct imports. Would you mind sharing the complete code?

Comment: I added it. Pretty much is a regular html file

Comment: Add this ```<form method="POST" action="/form">``` instead of ```<form>```. So it will go to the correct endpoint and it will know the HTTP method to submit.

Comment: wow it works now which is strange because before I did have action and method on my form and I took it out to test but didn't work even with it? What changed?

Comment: I am not sure, I always thought your initial code was correct!